# How did the servant know that the Lord was with David in 1 Samuel 16:18

Tags: 1-samuel, david

How did one of the servants of Saul know that the Lord was with David in 1 Samuel 16:18?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best indication of what the young servant of Saul meant when he said "the LORD is with him" is found in the rest of the quote: "Behold, I have seen a son of Jesse the Bethlehemite, who is skillful in playing, a man of valor, a man of war, prudent in speech, and a man of good presence, and the Lord is with him.”

This servant saw several distinguishing characteristics in David:

1. He was a skillful musician.
2. He was brave, a man of valor.
3. He was skilled with weapons, a man of war.
4. He was prudent, or wise, in his speech.
5. He was "a man of good presence," someone who has charisma and obvious leadership potential.

The servant thus concluded that a man this gifted must be blessed by the Lord, and so he wrapped up his assessment by saying "the Lord is with him." In other words, I don't think he was claiming any prophetic insight into David's destiny, but making a theologically informed assessment of David's character and abilities as evidence of being blessed by God.

Comment: Could you please re-frame this as a question?  If you are suggesting a possible "conclusion" - it is actually appropriate to post it as an answer, separately from the question, (below).

Comment: David found a favor of God, he also found favor of Saul and Jonathan as we see in the 1 Samuel.